# iOS 8 - Dynamic Content in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to make a UITableView with X number of cells. Each of the cells can have anywhere from 2 - 20+ views on it, but the number of views shouldn't be hardcoded.

So the first UITableViewCell might only have 3 Labels, whereas the second UITableViewCell might have 6 labels on it.

How can I implement this? I'm having difficulty just having the content appear, and having the correct height for the UITableView.

My current solution is to generate the content in a method (since I can't generate in the init method) and then add the subviews to the contentView after I pass the information to the cell. So far, this is creating bad results (the heights of the cells aren't calculated correctly).

This is the method of the UITableViewCell to generate the content.

```
- (void) generateContent
{

    // Simplifying the code, but this section will be hooked up with a property on the UITableViewCell to generate the content
    UIView *pmv = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PortalModuleView"
                                                      owner:self
                                                    options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    UIView *pmv2 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PortalModuleView"
                                                      owner:self
                                                    options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    // add the views
    [self.contentView addSubview:pmv];
    [self.contentView addSubview:pmv2];

    // add in some constraints


}
```

This is the datasource of the UITableView

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    ViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [cell generateContent];
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100;
}
```

The problem is that the cell doesn't generate the content I want (which I believe to be due to a bad height; the constraints rely on the height being correct). I think the main cause is just that the cell can't generate the right height until after the view has been generated.

I've tried using `reloadRowsAtIndexPath` but it doesn't fix the issue for all of the rows.

Comment: add some sample code you have tried, and the problem where you are stuck

Comment: what's the logic for your cell height? Why is it hardcoded?

Comment: That was just a hardcoded starting point; I was under the impressions that because I was using `estimatedHeight` it would automatically correct the height of cell for me (I'm using Auto Layout inside the cell). I just realized I can calculate the height of the UITableView cell's before hand though

Comment: Oh I see, use UITableViewAutomaticDimension for that. But calculate the height and pass it in heightForRowAtIndexPath: this will fix cell height problem. I think you need to call [cell generateContent]; in cellForRowAtIndexPath:  before returning the cell

Comment: It works if you pre-calculates the heights. I don't think it works just from using UITableViewAutomaticDimension (I did call `cell generateContent` before returning the cell), and the row height is 44. Is there anything else to try for that? I can work with pre-calculating the heights but it would make my life easier if I didn't have to

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own UITablewViewController that handles all that programmatically. There are number of methods in UITableViewController class you can overwrite to modify the table content.

For example, you can change the cell height like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   switch (indexPath.section)
   {
       case 0: // first section
       {
           switch (indexPath.row)
           {
               // first row of first section height
               case 0: return 48.0f;
               default: NSAssert(NO, @"Invalid row %d", (int)indexPath.row);
           } 
       } break;

       default: NSAssert(NO, @"Invalid section %d", (int)indexPath.section);
   }
}
```

Next you overwrite the cellForRowAtIndexPath & willDisplayCell -functions. If you don't want to generate the views programmatically you could always design your cell prototypes in storyboard-view and just fill the content programmatically:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell* cell = nil;
   NSString* cellID = nil;
   switch (indexPath.section)
   {
      case 0: cellID = MY_CELL_ID_FOR_CELLS_IN_SECTION_1; break;
      case 1: cellID = MY_CELL_ID_FOR_CELLS_IN_SECTION_2; break;
      default: NSAssert(NO, @"Invalid section %d", (int)indexPath.section); break;
   }
   if (cellID != nil)
   {
      cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
   }
   return cell;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   switch (indexPath.section)
   {
      case 0:
      {
          switch (indexPath.row)
          {
             case 0:
             {
                // Say your cell prototype has label with tag=1; You can fill the content like this:
                [(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1] setText:@"Hello!"];
             } break;
          }
      } break;
   }
}
```

see [UITableViewController class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/index.html) for more information